# how can i get last inserted id in laravel 8 using elequent model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

i want to get the last iserted id in my table to affect it into an other table i've  tried thosz but it doesnt work getPdo()->lastInsertId(), also lastInsertId()

```
   public function create()
    {

        $demande_inscription=Demande_inscription::create([
            'id_demandeur' => Demandeur::getPdo()->lastInsertId(),


        ]);
        return response()->json([$demande_inscription],201);


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For Laravel**

```
$user = new User();

$user->name = 'Rakesh';

$user->save();

//Getting Last inserted id

$insertedId = $user->id;
```

Answer (score 2):

if you are using eloquent then the object of the class that is used to create/save record is having the id of the record you inserted, let me explain it below

```
$object = new Model();
$object->DBfield = Data;
$object->save();

// After saving your record
$object->id;
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use insertGetId() from Query Builder.

```
use illuminate\Support\Facades\DB; 
... 

$id = DB::table('your_table')->insertGetId(['your associative array']);
```

In Eloquent Way :

```
$model = Model::create(['array']);
$id    = $model->id;
```

[Queries](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries)
[Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent)

Comment: this is not eloquent way rather query builder way